# Overwriting PHP variable and remembering it

Tags: php, html, variables, pagination, session-variables

So I have some data in MySQL being shown on my PHP page inside a table. I've set it up so that each page only displays 3 results each (temporary until it goes live, then it will be more). Everything works fine and it displays those 3 results on each page just fine.

What I want to do is be able to change the amount of results on each page right from the main PHP page. I can change the amount shown on that one page, but as soon as I go to page 2, it resets to 3 results. How can I remember the number stored in the variable, and display it on every page? I tried using SESSIONS, but I couldn't get it to work. I'm still a beginner btw.

```
$item = $_REQUEST['item'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['item'])){
    $limit=$item;
}
else{
    $limit=3;
}

//A few lines down -->    

<form action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post">
    Items: <input type="text" name="item">
    <input type="submit" name"go" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: What was the problem you were having with sessions?

Comment: Web development being "stateless" the sessions are probably the solution you are looking for.  Say you want a drop down for number for results and the user can select the value.  Sessions would be used most likely to persist that value.  With the actually assignment either being stored in session or tied to session and stored in database... Or can do what your code seems to suggest, keep taking on current `limit` to every subsequent request.  Thing is there it will not truly 'persist' the way you might desire.

Comment: I couldn't get them to work. It wouldn't change at all and would just stay at the default 3.

Comment: The use a constant?  see `DEFINE`.

Comment: did you use [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add SESSION use this way:

```
$item = $_REQUEST['item'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['item'])){
    $limit=$item;
    $_SESSION['item_limit'] = $limit;
}
else{
    // If we find a limit set in the session use that
    if (!empty($_SESSION['item_limit']) {
        $limit = $_SESSION['item_limit'];
    }
    else {
        $limit=3;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. I was just messing around with it sessions before you posted this and I got it to remember across multiple pages, but after it was set, I couldn't change the value.

So if it was 3 before, and I changed it to 2 it would work the way I wanted it to. I couldn't change it to 1 though, which was the problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to remember the value the next time the user visits the page you can simply output the $limit as a value attribute for the "item" input.

```
Items: <input type="text" name="item" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>">
```